# Wizard like layout in android

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I want to create a Wizard like layout which should look like described:
 * at the top should be some kind of title of the current dialog
 * at the bottom should be a navigation bar containg buttons for next/previous and various operations. THis bar should always(!) be at the very bottom of the screen.
 * at the center should be a list (should use all the space left, except the title bar and the navigation bar described above)

My first attempt is posted below. I used framelayout however I was told this is a bad idea. The problem I ran into is that last row of my list is below the bar with the buttons at the bottom of the screen. Do you have any suggestions on how I could solve my Problem?

Thanks

Here's my not working draft:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@android:style/ButtonBar">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/person"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:text="@string/personstring"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView android:visibility="visible" android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" style="@android:style/ButtonBar">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/loacreation.previousButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:src="@drawable/buttonarrowleft" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/loacreation.nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:src="@drawable/buttonarrowright" />
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a RelativeLayout as your outermost container, and the LinearLayout that contains your buttons can have android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".